# bash script var not changed after the loop

Tags: bash

I'm quite new to bash scripting, and I wrote the following script to emulate the `wc -c` command: (I know it doesn't count the end of the line)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
len=0
cat $1 | while read line
do
    let len+=${#line}
    echo $len
done
echo $len
```

the output is the following:

```
xyz.sh
11
11
18
27
51
53
70
79
83
92
0
```

why doesn't `len` stays changed after the loop, and hoe to make it to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because your `while` loop is being run in a subshell. Variable modifications in the subshell don't affect the parent.

Avoid both the pipe and the useless use of `cat` by doing some redirection instead:

```
while read line
do
    let len+=${#line}
    echo $len
done < $1
```

This doesn't require a subshell, so changes to `$len` will be visible in the parent.